# Proving standard basis of $l^p$, $1<p<\infty$, to be shrinking

Tags: functional-analysis, schauder-basis

The definition of shrinking basis is given inside the  [Wikipedia article](https://m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis), under the section "Schauder basis and Duality". It says that "if $1<p<\infty$, then the standard basis $(e_n)_n$ is shrinking". I need help to prove this statement.

Comment: Can you show that if $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty} \Vert \sum_{n\geq m} a_n e_n \Vert_{\ell^p} =0$ for $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n e_n \in \ell^p$? Then use the isomorphism $\ell^p \cong \ell^q$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}=1$. Also it helps if you spell out what you have tried.

Comment: Yes I can show and as you mentioned, each functional on $l^p$ can be identified with an element of $l^q$, yet it is not quite clear to me because there is "supremum" in the definition, i don't understand how can I take limit without passing through it. It will be helpful if you elaborate your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix $y\in\ell^q$ and then estimate
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum_{m=n}^\infty x_my_m\Big|
\end{align}
for $x\in\ell^p$ with $\|x\|_p=1$. So
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum_{m=n}^\infty x_my_m\Big|
\leq\Big(\sum_{m=n}^\infty |x_m|^p\Big)^{1/p}
\Big(\sum_{m=n}^\infty |y_m|^q\Big)^{1/q}
\leq\Big(\sum_{m=n}^\infty |y_m|^q\Big)^{1/q}.
\end{align}